# How Can I set block at the starting of the page

Tags: latex, overleaf

Hi all someone know how I can put the block at the start of the page instead skipping 5 cm?

```
      \documentclass{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=1080px,paperheight=1980px}

\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space above your block is for the title, but you can adjust the position via the optional argument to `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=1080px,paperheight=1980px}

\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]